# What's the meaning of the exclamation point in the triangle next to my Calendars?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, calendar

System details:
OSX 10.11.6 (15G1212)
Calendar Version 8.0 (2092.3)

I have a few Calendar subscriptions shared between my Mac and iPhone, including a few shared with multiple people.  I noticed that on my Mac, when I open Calendar, there are 'exclamation point in a triangle' icons next to two of my groups of calendars.

What are these icons indicating?

[image: Calendar Screenshot with Icons]

Comment: That indicates a communication/sync problem.  Try deleting those calendars and re-add them.  That usually solves it.

Comment: You could also try deleting the cache files as mentioned here: https://michaelkummer.com/tech/apple/macos-calendar-exchange/